# vb.net shared leave event and how to determine which shared box caused the leave

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a new assignment. Our instructor wants us to code a shared leave event for three textboxes (txtBox1, txtBox2, txtBox3).
I understand how to code the shared event and how to make a generic tbox for it:

```
Private Sub txtDescription_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBox1.Leave, txtBox2.Leave, txtBox3.Leave

    'generic textbox
    Dim txtText As TextBox
    txtText = CType(sender, TextBox)
```

We are told that if the generic textbox contains data **and** the data has been modified (against the database record), we need to :

Determine the name (name property) of the textbox that casued the evend
and
Determine the value (text property) of that textbox.

I know to check to see if anything is in the generic box by the length property, and if it is modified by the modified method, but how do you determine the name and value? Is it a case statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have everything that you need right there.  The **sender Object** is the `TextBox` that is triggering the event

```
Private Sub txtDescription_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBox1.Leave, txtBox2.Leave, txtBox3.Leave 

    'generic textbox 
    Dim txtText As TextBox 
    Dim txtName as String
    Dim txtValue as String

    txtText = CType(sender, TextBox) 
    txtName= txtText.Name
    txtValue = txtText.Text
```

Answer (score 2):

The name is `txtText.Name` and the value is `txtText.Text` (after your CType call).

Comment: But if I am instructed to "Determine the name of the tb that has triggered the event and find the value of the tb", should I not find out the specific box (1,2,or3) that caused it? How do you do that?

Comment: @PhillCookie: That's exactly what txtText.Name provides. When you look at this value, you will see the exact name of the control (txtBox1, txtBox2, or txtBox3) as a string.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your patience. I know this is pretty much remedial vb, but I just needed to get my beginner head around it.
So I would then just need to do an if statement, as in:
If txtText.text.length > 0 and txtText.modified
   txtName = txtText.Name
   txtValue = txtText.Text
End If? (I don't think this formats correctly, sorry)